# Call a procedure(by an event) whose name is set by another procedure

Tags: delphi

I want a procedure to be executed when an event is happened. But that procedure is set by another procedure(`SetNotifierProc`).

Firstly I run this:

```
SetNotifierProc(Proc1);
```

And then `Proc1` is executed whenever event triggered.

How could I code `SetNotifierProc` to get a procedure as an argument and how to inform event handler to execute that procedure?

Problem: I have a `TCPServerExecute` and want to run a procedure to show received data. But because I have multiple forms I want to set a procedure that handle received data.

Thanks

Comment: Store the procedure-reference into a variable and call that reference inside event-handler-method?

Comment: Nice, but What's the data type of that variable? And how to do this?

Comment: e.g. TMyProc = procedure( AParam : Integer );

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your procedure is an ordinary procedure without arguments:

```
Type
  TForm1 = Class(TForm)
    ..
     private

     FMyProc : TProcedure;
   public
     procedure SetEventProc(aProc : TProcedure);
     procedure TheEvent( Sender : TObject);
  end;

procedure Test;
begin
  // Do something
end;

procedure TForm1.SetEventProc(aProc: TProcedure);
begin
  Self.FMyProc := aProc;
end;

procedure TForm1.TheEvent(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(FMyProc) then
    FMyProc;
end;

// to set the callback to procedure "Test"
Form1.SetEventProc(Test);
```

If your procedure has arguments, declare a procedure type:

```
Type
  MyProcedure = procedure( aString : String);
```

And if your procedure is a method :

```
Type
  MyMethod = procedure( aString : String) of Object;
```

See also documentation about [`Procedural types`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Procedural_Types).

Comment: Worked. Thanks a lot (I used `TProc` instead of `TProcedure` because in my case `Test` is a class method)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick :-

```
Type
  TTCPNotifyProc = Procedure(pData : String) Of Object;

TMyTCPServer = Class
Private
  FNotifyProc : TTCPNotifyProc;
..
Public
  Procedure SetNotifier(pProc : TTCPNotifyProc);
End;

Procedure TMyTCPServer.SetNotifier(pProc : TTCPNotifyProc);
Begin
  FNotifyProc := pProc;
End;
```

Then whenever you need to call the procedure within your server class just call :-

```
If Assigned(FNotifyProc) Then
  FNotifyProc(DataStringReceived);
```